# How to fill the Area under a Bezier curve in Android

Tags: android, android-view, fill, bezier

I'm searching for a way of filling the Area under a cubic Bezier curve in Android. To be specific I'm trying to draw a Figure like in the Picture below in a Custom View. My idea is to draw a circle and two mirrored cubic Bezier curves and fill the area beneath them. Is there an Android built in way to archive this, or do I have to find another solution? If so can you help me find an alternative solution?

The shape I would like to draw:

[image: The shape I would like to draw]

Answer (score 6):

What you need here is `Path`. More info here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

1. In your case, you need to create a `Path`
2. Move that to a point that you want via `path.moveTo()`
3. Add the first bezier curve via `path.cubicTo()`
4. Add the circle to the path via `path.addCircle()`
5. Add the second bezier curve via `path.cubicTo()`
6. Finally, close the path via `path.close()`

As for the fill of the path. Normally, the path is filled inside. If you are looking for something else, I suggest you play around with `path.setFillType()`.